# Navigation with abstract base fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have a setup like the navigation graph below. The 3 fragments in the middle are very similar and all extend a `BaseFragment` class.

[image]

What I would like to do is to make `BaseFragment` abstract, so that my navigation graph can be reduced to the figure below.

[image]

Is this even possible? It would drastically reduce the clutter of my navigation graph, because there will eventually be upwards of 20 children. However, I think this improvement would require me to instantiate an abstract class, which isn't possible.

Comment: You're looking for arguments, not an abstract class

Comment: I don't quite understand how that solves the problem.  Are you saying use the second picture, but make `BaseFragment` non-abstract and just pass it an argument to indicate which child to use? Each child fragment uses the same xml template and inserts slightly different views into the template, so I need to ensure that I can populate my views correctly.

Comment: Sounds like they don't need a common base then.

Comment: They definitely benefit from a common base. They all do the same functions, they just vary slightly in the implementation. If I eliminate the common base, then I have more duplicate code than unique code.

Comment: Sounds like a usecase for a compound viewgroup or a common "controller" of sorts, but doesn't sound like the behavior should be coming from a common parent fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a `Fragment` cannot be abstract.

The solution I decided upon was to have a helper class that stores the data I want to display in my Fragment. This helper class has a child for each of the original `ChildFragment` classes.

I can dynamically population my Fragment by simply reading the data stored in this helper class, thus allowing me to implement the second figure in the question.

Comment: `No, a Fragment cannot be abstract.`

How do you come to a conclusion like this? A Fragment can certainly have an abstract BaseFragment class, and that is what I am doing in my project right now.